# is there any property in rgraph to give space between the label and graph?

Tags: rgraph

[image: is there any property in rgraph to give space between the label and graph?]

How to add space in between the graph and the label(Apr 5)?

Answer (score 1):

If you upgrade to the latest version (which is now 6.07) then you can use the xaxisLabelsOffsetx property.

Your chart will also look more "3D-ish" like the chart on the front page:

https://www.rgraph.net

And here's the documentation entry for your property:

https://www.rgraph.net/canvas/bar.html#property-name-xaxisLabelsOffsetx